# Rerun all db migrations on Heroku (rake db:migrate:reset)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

While developing a heroku app, before launch, I have been keeping my migrations into 2 files (Create Users, Create Posts) instead of adding a new migration everytime I change the structure of the tables (probably would be 20 iterations at this point). There is no data in the db yet.

How can I do `rake db:migrate:reset`'s equivalent on Heroku? Heroku does not allow this. I was thinking I could do `heroku pg:reset` and then `rake db:migrate`, but this doesn't seem to rerun old migrations. Again, there is no data in Heroku's database, so it can be dropped.

migrations:

- 2014070781234_create_users_table **I added a column in this
  migration. It has already been run on heroku. How can I rerun it so
  the table is updated?**
- 2014070789999_create_posts_table

Comment: did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` or just rake db:migrate ?

Comment: I have run `heroku run rake db:migrate`. However I do not believe that reruns old migrations. (see above, I'm trying to rerun a migration that has already run in the past)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You should not make changes in your migration files which have already been migrated**. If you look at [`docs`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations) it says

`In general, editing existing migrations is not a good idea. You will be creating extra work for yourself and your co-workers and cause major headaches if the existing version of the migration has already been run on production machines. Instead, you should write a new migration that performs the changes you require`

You should create a new migration file by

```
rails g migration AddColumnNameToUsers column_name:type
```

This will generate a migration file like:

```
class AddColumnNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :column_name, :type
  end
end
```

And then you can simply run **heroku run rake db:migrate**

If you still want to Drop your database from heroku then you need to do:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm nameofapp
```

and then **heroku run rake db:migrate**. For details checkout [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks Mandeep, in this case I made the choice to avoid the large number of migration files in favor of this approach. I am just working by myself and found this to be a lot cleaner before there was data in the DB.

Comment: @DonnyP Okay! You can reset your database by using `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm nameofapp`

Comment: What's the difference of this "heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm nameofapp" and "heroku rake db:migrate:redo"?

Comment: @bitfrost41 rake db:migrate:redo is a shortcut for doing a rollback and then migrating back up again. You can use step option with to specify how many migrations you want to redo. Reset will drop your whole database and rebuild it again, equivalent to db:drop and db:setup.